# Youtube private access management via API or library

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a situation where I need to invite users to to be able to watch a private playlist on videos on Youtube.

I have found information about this at: [Add or remove access to your YouTube channel](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9481328?hl=en)

However that uses the user interface (Youtube page) and I'm looking for doing it in a programmatic way.

The best I found about managing channels is this: [Implementation: Channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/channels?hl=en) however there is nothing about invites and access removing.

Is there a way to invite users and and remove a user's permission using the YouTube API or a library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way to add or remove permissions on channels though the YouTube Data api.

You might want to check though the issue log and see if anyone has already submitted a feature request for this.  [YouTube Issue forum.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)